# PHP array_sum outputs individual numbers rather than as a whole

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have this list of "coupons" each with a unique "productid"

[image: coupons]

Now I am trying to convert the list into an array using:

```
$claimed = array($rowOrder['productid']);
```

My issue is when I try to use "count" and "array_sum" it outputs individual numbers:

```
$count_claimed = array(count($claimed));
echo array_sum($count_claimed);
```

Using the echo I get and output of: "1111111"
What should I change to get a sum count of 7? (as displayed with the number of "coupons")

additional info:

The "coupons" are being outputted by this `SELECT` statement, `$rowOrder` is calling this.

```
public function SelectLst_ByUsrCustomerIDInfo($db, $usrcustomerid) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
      " SELECT o.orderid, o.productid, o.usrcustomerid, o.amount, o.amountrefunded, o.createddate, o.scheduleddate, o.useddate, o.expirationdate, p.photosrc
        FROM `order` o LEFT JOIN `product` p ON o.productid = p.productid

        WHERE usrcustomerid = :usrcustomerid"
    );

    $stmt->bindValue(':usrcustomerid', $usrcustomerid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $rows;
}
```

This is called like this

```
$lstInfo = $mcOrder->SelectLst_ByUsrCustomerIDInfo($db, $usrcustomerid);
foreach($lstInfo as $rowOrder) {
    if (isset($rowOrder['productid']) && ($rowOrder['expirationdate'] >  date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))) {
        $claimed = array($rowOrder['productid']);
        $count_claimed = array(count($claimed));
        echo array_sum($count_claimed);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$claimed = array($rowOrder['productid']);` will also be an array of length *one*. You probably want to push it to an array instead of assign it to an array, then use `count()` alone (`array_sum()` will sum all values of an array consisting of many numbers).

Comment: You should show some more code - do you fetch this data from a query? If so, can you share that code?

Comment: updated my question with additional info

Comment: And how do you call `SelectLst_ByUsrCustomerIDInfo`? Show that code as well.

Comment: updated question again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `count($lstInfo)` you will get the total number of fetched rows (`PDOStatement::fetchAll()` returns an array, and you just count the number of elements in it). Then you can loop the results and increment a variable called `$claimed` if the condition is true.

```
$lstInfo = $mcOrder->SelectLst_ByUsrCustomerIDInfo($db, $usrcustomerid);
$total = count($lstInfo);
$claimed = 0;
foreach($lstInfo as $rowOrder) {
    if (isset($rowOrder['productid']) && ($rowOrder['expirationdate'] >  date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))) {
         $claimed += 1;
    }
}
echo "Claimed $claimed of $total.";
```

Even better, you can do it in one query using a `COUNT()` and an added `WHERE` condition. This means you won't get the total, but that didn't seem to be the question to begin with either.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(productid) as cnt
                      FROM `order` o 
                      LEFT JOIN `product` p 
                           ON o.productid = p.productid
                      WHERE usrcustomerid = :usrcustomerid
                       AND expirationdate > NOW()
                      GROUP BY usrcustomerid");
$stmt->execute([":usrcustomerid" => $usrcustomerid]);
$result = $stmt->fetch();
echo "Claimed ".$result['cnt'];
```

Comment: i see, i need to count inside the for loop, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This,**

```
$claimed = array();
foreach($products as $rowOrder){
    array_push($claimed,$rowOrder['productid']);
}
echo count($claimed);
echo array_sum($claimed);die;
```